# Random ticket with if-else for biased lottery

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have the following already:

```
public class RandomTickets
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      final int MIN = 0, MAX = 3;
      int ticketQuant = ((int)(Math.random() * (MAX + 1 - MIN))) + MIN;

      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("You have won " + ticketQuant);
      System.out.println(ticketQuant == 1 ? " ticket." : " tickets.");
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

but what I want to do is to alter the program so that there is :

- 1 in 15 chance of winning 3 tickets
- 2 in 15 chance of winning 2 tickets
- 4 in 15 chance of winning 1 ticket

And I want to use switch statements.

Any ideas?!

Comment: How about generating a number between 1 and 15 (inclusive) instead? If the number is less than or equal to `4` then at least one ticket has been won. And so on (nesting `if` checks for the other two conditions).

Comment: As an addendum to my comment above, using a switch with fall-through cases is the way I would solve it. One common case for `4` and `3`, one for `2`, and finally one for `1`. Each case increment the "ticket" variable by one (initially initialized to zero of course). After the switch the "ticket" variable will be `1`, `2` or `3` with the probabilities you want.

Comment: Or perhaps I'm misunderstand you and the probabilities? Doesn't matter, just adjust the conditions in the `if` statements so that there will be exactly four numbers being valid (for example `randomNumber >= 4 && randomNumber <= 7`). Can still be solved with a switch, but now it makes a little more sense to use `if`. You can still "fall through" with the `if`, by not having any `else`. Then as with the fall-through switch cases just increase the "tickets" variable by one in each `if`.

Comment: do you mind showing me how to do this in code, in switch statements? i am very confused! :)

Comment: I'll let you think a little, let you try to figure it out yourself first. Then if you haven't solved it yourself *perhaps* I'll show you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Very straightforward solution:

```
final Random random = new Random();
final int r = 1 + random.nextInt(15);
final ticketCount;

if (r <= 4) {
    ticketCount = 1;
} else if (r <= 6) {
    ticketCount = 2;
} else if (r <= 7) {
    ticketCount = 3;
}
```

A bit more fancy:

```
ticketCount = ((r ^ 15) == 0 ? 3 : 0) + 
    (((r | 1) ^ 9) == 0 ? 2 : 0) +
    (((r | 3) ^ 7) == 0 ? 1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Designate numbers for each luck
    final List<Integer> luck1OutOf15 = Arrays.asList(1);
    final List<Integer> luck2OutOf15 = Arrays.asList(2, 3);
    final List<Integer> luck4OutOf15 = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6, 7);

    final Random random = new Random();
    final int luck = random.nextInt(15) + 1;
    final int ticketCount;
    if (luck1OutOf15.contains(luck)) {
        ticketCount = 3;
    } else if (luck2OutOf15.contains(luck)) {
        ticketCount = 2;
    } else if (luck4OutOf15.contains(luck)) {
        ticketCount = 1;
    } else {
        ticketCount = 0;
    }
```